# Increase the visibility range at a small scale for a georeferenced TIFF tile layer in ArcGIS Online

Tags: geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, zoom

I am building a webmap in ArcGIS Online whereby I will be importing multiple historical maps saved as TIFFs after first scanning them, saving them in Photoshop, and georeferencing them in ArcGIS Pro. When I imported the first map into AGOL, I noticed it was not visible beyond 1:4,622,324 despite having an unlimited visibility range in Pro and despite my attempt to set the minimum visible scale to a smaller figure. The images below first show the map at its default minimum visible scale, then its failure to appear even with the minimum visible scale adjusted.

[image]

[image]

Though I am new to georeferencing, the research I've done on this topic so far makes me think this is somehow related to the resolution the image was saved at. If this is true, is it possible to increase the visibility range beyond its default minimum scale without compromising the image's resolution (preferably without coding, since I know none beyond the most basic HTML)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the settings for the layer in ArcGIS Online, check the Tile Details. Expand that section and make sure you have tiles built for the entire range you want visible on your map. If there are no tiles built for your desired zoom level, the raster will not display regardless of how you have visibility set.

[image]

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, having a "0" under "Tiles Published" at any scale means the tiles are available but have not been built yet? And if all scales are at 100% complete (as is the case with my webmap), this means I have no available tiles to build?

Comment: Correct, if there is a 0 under Tiles Published those tiles have not been built. You can click the blue Build Tiles button if you need to add additional tile levels. If you have everything at 100%, then yeah it looks like you already have all tiles. This has tripped me up in the past, so I figured it was worth it for you to check since it's a relatively common issue.